# Does the @FetchRequest property wrapper automatically notify when changes happen?

Tags: core-data, swiftui

If I'm using an NSPersistentCloudKitContainer, I see in the sqlite file that changes are automatically synced. I can also make changes in the CloudKit Dashboard, restart the app and see the changes. If I use `@FetchRequest` to load some items, should the items array automatically update?

```swift
// Fetch some items
@FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

// Show them in a List

List(items) { item in
  VStack {
    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you set `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true` which is not in the default code provided by Apple when you check Use CoreData and CloudKit.

```swift
let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "MyApp")
container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
```